# Do loading screen tips change depending on level?

Tags: fallout-4

I have a character that I think is below level 20 and while I was fast-traveling, I noticed the item on the loading screen was a modified pipe rifle. I realized that I never saw this loading screen item anymore on my level 106 character.

Am I still able to see that item, along with its respective tip message, or am I simply "unlucky" to not have seen it for as long as it's been?

Comment: I have no idea about your question. But the wiki does have a list with all [loading screens](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_loading_screens).

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time reviewing resources related to this online and was unable to find anything comprehensive. I think at best we'll have anecdotal evidence to support any answers.

Speaking from experience I believe loading screens *are* influenced by your character level; they are also influenced the locations you've visited and milestone's you've achieved. For instance I did not see any loading screens related to Goodneighbor until I actually visited the location. Likewise, I did not see loading screens with information about assualtrons and sentry bots until my character was higher than level 30*.

However, I do not believe that loading screens have a maximum level they appear to the player. Rather, as your character levels up and achieves more milestones more loading screens are added to the loading screen pool and you are less likely to see existing screens. They don't disappear entirely, they do appear less frequently.

*approximately

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, me having cheated levels many times. It's based on where you have been in the game, quests, and other stuff. So like at the start, when you're in the vault the loading screen is the vault 111 door (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Stack Exchange's question-and-answer format is a little different than conversation forums you may be used to. Answers have to stand alone, but this reads like it is intended to be part of a conversation.